# How can I specify that one instruction should be performed at the end of execution?

Tags: c, order-of-execution

In other words:
Is it possible to delay a certain instruction, like a `printf` in a way so that it's executed **exactly** at the very end of execution?

Comment: Are you looking for [`atexit`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/atexit) function?

Comment: I'm going to try to solve my issue with that one, thanks :)

Comment: Does this work on Windows, too?

Comment: it should, it's an ANSI C <stdlib.h> function

Comment: @h0ch5tr4355 as you can see in my answer, `atexit()` is part of `stdlib.h`, so it's ANSI C.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote an example of usage of [`atexit`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/atexit.html):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void foo(void) {
    printf("\nDone!\n");
}

int main(void) {
    atexit(foo);
    for (;;) {
        int tmp = rand() % 100; // unseeded
        printf("%02d ", tmp);
        if (!tmp) break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

As usual, you should check the return value of `atexit()` to check for errors. Also be aware that terminating the program with `_Exit()` or abnormal process termination (eg: *division by zero*) does not call the functions specified in `atexit()` call(s).

<kbd>[Live demo](https://ideone.com/mHcOKd)</kbd>

The output could be (not copied from ideone)

```
18 42 02 00 
Done!
```

Comment: A complete answer should include discussion of when functions registered by `atexit` are not called and discussion of `at_quick_exit` and registering a handler for the abort signal.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I've not been maintaining myself up to date since ... hmmm ... since I stopped using usenet. The POSIX site makes no reference to `at_quick_exit`: I didn't even know it exists until 2 minutes ago. I'm editing my answer with the other info, thank you.

Comment: If the reader wants more information about `at_quick_exit` it's in [C11 Standard 7.22.4.3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.4.3).

Comment: @pmg: distressingly enough, we also find [`_Exit`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.4.5) in there, intended to use `exit` without calling `atexit` (nor, indeed, `at_quick_exit`). Yet we came so far without such embellishments...

Comment: @pmg: Yes, the information is in the C standard. That does not alter the fact that this answer is incomplete without it. A person seeking to create an exit handler ought to be informed about the circumstances in which various handlers may or may not be executed and what can be done about it, as that information is necessary to achieve the goal.

Comment: You probably meant `_Exit()` not `_exit()`.

Answer (score 1):

The C language provides atexit for this:

[atexit](https://linux.die.net/man/3/atexit) - register a function to be called at normal process termination

Answer (score 1):

You want [`int atexit (void (*func)(void));`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atexit/)

> The function pointed by `func` is automatically called without arguments
>   when the program *terminates* normally.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>      /* puts */
#include <stdlib.h>     /* atexit */

void fnExit1(void) {
  puts("Exit function 1.");
}

void fnExit2(void) {
  puts("Exit function 2.");
}

int main(void) {
  atexit(fnExit1);
  atexit(fnExit2);
  puts("Main function.");
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Main function.
Exit function 2.
Exit function 1.
```

Comment: The description of [`atexit()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/atexit.html) in the POSIX documentation does not have an example, but may be preferrable than the one in *...plusplus...* :)

Comment: Yeah @pmg, I was formating a bit your answer, and I was ready to upvote, but you deleted! Thanks for helping... PS: In start I used a Linux ref as well, which lacked an example, that's why I switched to cpluscplus, which I know that it can look strange (I remember when I was linked to it while learning C in the first semester, and was like what is this). ;)